# RabbitMQ/Azure - Connect to RabbitMQ set up on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: .net, azure, rabbitmq, azure-virtual-machine, azure-marketplace

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ on Azure Virtual Machine Server, which I created using Azure Marketplace.

**Configuration**

1 – I open azure portal -> Market place -> search for RabbitMQ Server -> Create **“RabbitMQ Server on Windows Server 2016”** -> I leave everything on default (I only change Size to Standard_B2s) -> Click on “Create”

2 – I open my Virtual machine resources on Portal -> Networking -> It looks more or less like this:

| Priority | Name | Port |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1010 | RabbitMQ80 | 80 |
| 1020 | RabbitMQ443 | 443 |
| 1030 | RabbitMQ15672 | 15672 |
| 1040 | default-allow-rdp | 3389 |
| 65000 | AllowVnetInBound | Any |
| 65001 | AllowAzureLoadBalancerInBound | Any |
| 65500 | DenyAllInBound | Any |

3 – I connect to Virtual Machine using Remote Desktop -> Open Internet Explorer -> Internet options -> Security -> Add **localhost** to **Trusted sites** -> Open **localhost:15672** –> I see that RabbitMQ is working.

4 – I log into RabbitMQ -> Admin -> I add a **new Admin user** with password and **"Can access virtual hosts"** set to **“/”**.

5 – On my local PC I open browser -> type: **{virtual-machine-ip}:15672** -> I see that RabbitMQ is working. -> I tried to log in using **new Admin user** - it worked.

**Question**

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ on Azure Virtual Machine using this code:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
    HostName = "{vm-ip}",
    UserName = "{new-user}",
    Password = "{new-user-pass}",
    VirtualHost = "/",
    Port = 80
};
using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();
```

And I am getting this exception:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: „None of the specified endpoints were reachable”

I am sure that I miss some configuration, but I can not find which one. Also, using port **5672** or **15672** does not help. (I added **5672** in **Networking** rules.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016159/how-to-solve-this-error-rabbitmq-client-exceptions-brokerunreachableexception > did you happen to check the solution here? and here -https://github.com/devmentors/DNC-DShop/issues/8

Comment: @SiddheshDesai password for my new user has no special characters. Also, I tried to use `factory.Uri = "amqp://user:pass@hostName:port/vhost";` - also did not help.

Comment: Are you running the code from the same rabitMQ server or another Azure VM? If another azure vm can you allow another Azure vm's IP in rabit mq's NSG?

Comment: I am running the code from my local machine. Also, I can connect to RabbitMQ on Virtual Machine using: {virtual-machine-ip}:15672

Comment: In your network table above is port 5672 also allowed?

Comment: Did you try with the default username and password?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I added port 5672 to table above - did not help. I tried default username - did not work (PS: default username works only on localhost in RabbitMQ).